# Django test taking 20min+ (sometimes)

Tags: python, django, docker, testing, factory-boy

I have a mysterious test that's taking much longer to run than it should. I have tried to debug it for a while now but I've run out of creativity. The test does create a lot of database records, but still, it's only a few hundreds, I could understand it taking one minute, but definitely not 20. Here's the relevant code that chokes for some reason:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase

class MyTest(APITestCase, ...):

    ...

    def setUp(self):
        self.setup_questions()

    def setup_questions(self):
        question_levels = [
                QuestionLevelFactory.create(title="Major", ...),
                QuestionLevelFactory.create(title="Minor", ...),
                QuestionLevelFactory.create(title="Recommended", ...)
            ]

            questionnaire1 = QuestionnaireFactory.create(...)
            questionnaire2 = QuestionnaireFactory.create(...)

            possible_answer_set = PossibleAnswerSetFactory.create(...)

            for question_level in question_levels:
                if question_level.title == "Recommended":
                    questionnaire = questionnaire2
                    counter = 25
                else:
                    questionnaire = questionnaire1
                    counter = 100
                for i in range(counter):
                    if i <= 97:
                        question = QuestionFactory.create(
                            level_object=question_level, possible_answer_set=possible_answer_set,
                            questionnaire=questionnaire
                        )
                    else:
                        question = QuestionFactory.create(
                            level_object=question_level, possible_answer_set=possible_answer_set,
                            questionnaire=questionnaire, code="{}-{}".format(question_level.title, i)
                        )

                    if i < 95:
                        AnswerFactory.create(
                            question=question, assessment=self.assessment, value="yes"
                        )
                    elif i <= 97:
                        AnswerFactory.create(
                            question=question, assessment=self.assessment, value="not_applicable"
                        )
                    else:
                        AnswerFactory.create(
                            question=question, assessment=self.assessment, value="no",
                            justification="{} {} justification".format(question_level.title, i)
                        )
```

Note that, when the `question_levels` are listed in this order, the test only starts chocking when processing the "Minor" level. The first one ("Major") one is processed *much* faster. When I switch Minor and Major, things are slow from the beginning.

This is a legacy project that I started working on rather recently, so I don't know exactly what could be happening behind the curtains, but honestly I can't imagine anything that would cause such a strange behavior.

I'm running my Django app in a Docker container and connection to a Postgres server in another. Using SQLite doesn't really help, still takes very long.

Relevant library versions:

```
Django==1.9.13
django-factory-boy==0.1.6
factory-boy==2.7.0
fake-factory==0.7.2
```

Any suggestions/ideas are highly appreciated.

Comment: are you watching any save signals or overriding the save method in your models? also it would be a good idea to provide a [mcve] :P

Comment: Thanks. I muted signals for some of my tests and it did help at first. Unfortunately I cannot make it minimal, complete and verifiable. It's a large project and I haven't managed to reproduce this problem with a simple setup. What I can add is that the whole test suite takes over an hour to run, and several tests take over 5 minutes. I have tried different solutions, and sometimes it works and the whole suite passes in under a minute (like now when I first muted the signals). But at some point it always starts taking over 30min again (like now after a few runs). It's very unpredictable.

Comment: Consider creating shared fixtures either on class level or module level. Your `setUp` method is run once for every test case that inherits from `MyTest`
https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#class-and-module-fixtures

Comment: Also every call to `QuestionFactory.create()` in that loop results in a individual database transaction/query. Instead use `bulk_create` to create multiple fixture objects in a single db query https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: Did you ever find out why this was happening?